# Creating a shared date service that can be read and updated by multiple components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, observable

I have a service that provides me a date. I created a service that will consume this date and format it and then provide it to various other components that use this date as a param to call other services. The user is  able to go to any of these components and change the date

I tried using an Observable but I can't update the values and I am unfamiliar with their conception and usage in this scenario

```
@Component({
  selector: 'date',
  templateUrl: './date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date.component.css']
 })
 export class DateComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedDate: any;
  maxDate: any;

  constructor(private dateService: HeatmapDateService) {
    this.getAsOfDate().subscribe(date => {
      let formatDate = new Date(date);
      this.selectedDate = formatDate.setDate(formatDate.getDate() + 1);
      this.maxDate = this.selectedDate;
    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  getAsOfDate(){
    return this.dateService.get()
  }
```

The HTML that uses the service

```
      <mat-form-field>
        <input readonly matInput [max]="dateService.maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="dateService.selectedDate"
               (ngModelChange)="updateDate($event)">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Within my other services I use dependency injection to add the date service to the constructor and I want to update the value of selected date when the user picks a new date from the date picker but I can't seem to figure out how to set up the date component to provide a date to the datepicker and when the date is changed I call the updateDate function to change the value of the date in the dateService but I can't update an observable and ngModel doesn't seem to work like this.

Comment: that's a bit too broad and can't provide a full answer now, but create in your service an observable property (or `subject`) and subscribe to it where you need to listen for updates. Then in y our service, when you update the value, trigger the `next` on the subject to output a new value to all the subscribers

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the docs, that the unput has a bit different syntax ([Datepicker input and change events example](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)). Have you tried it?

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Input & change events"
         (dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)" (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: No, how would I use the addEvent in this case to change the value in the service?

Comment: That won't work either, the date picker needs to display an initial value also received by the service which doesn't work like this

Comment: You can have a methon within the service which returns you initial date.